# Spring:Writing image from GridFS to jsp view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gridfs, spring-data-mongodb

I am using GridFS to store images. Now I want to write stored image to spring view page directly I have tried a lot, but not succeded. I can write image to my local system by using

```
gfs.writeTo("my location of local directory");
```

but how can I write same image to JSP view in spring? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

Serve method:

```
@Override
public void serveImage(String imageId , HttpServletResponse response ) {
    InputStream is = null;  

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoDBConfiguration.class);
    GridFsOperations gridOperations = (GridFsOperations) ctx.getBean("yourBeanName");

    List<GridFSDBFile> result = gridOperations.find(new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(imageId)));

    for (GridFSDBFile file : result) {
        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=image.jpg");
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            response.setContentLengthLong(file.getLength());

            is = file.getInputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

            response.flushBuffer();

        } catch (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
<image>
    <source th:src="@{/get/${imageId}}" type="image/jpg">
</image>
```

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void handleFileDownload(@PathVariable String imageId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        vaskService.serveImage(imageId,  response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }

}
```